# Why is the KubeEvents table empty in azure logs?

Tags: azure

In short: Why would my query for [KubeEvents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/reference/tables/kubeevents) be empty when `kubectl get events` is not empty ?

---

So my end goal is to have azure store kubernetes events in order to figure out why our pods are restarting.

I can query the events via `kubectl get events` however my understanding is these logs are only held for an hour.

My specific issue is when I query `kubectl get events`, I receive an event of type 'warning' that I expect to see when I query KubeEvents in azure logs.  But when I query KubeEvents, there are no results.  I ensured the time period being queried should encompass the event.

---

What I've looked into

1. I've read in [this faq](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/faq#why-don-t-i-see-normal-event-types-when-i-query-the-kubeevents-table-) how events with type "Normal" won't be collected, however my log has type "Warning"
2. I was looking into adding a [Diagnostic Setting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/diagnostic-settings?WT.mc_id=Portal-Microsoft_Azure_Monitoring), but from what I can tell KubeEvents are separate from those categories ?  Honestly I couldn't grok exactly what those settings were doing, the documentation felt vague considering my lack of familiarity with this environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created an AKS cluster and deployed a sample application to check the Kube events.
[image]

When I run `kubectl get events` for pods in cluster, it lists type `warning` for pods with pending status as below.

```
kubectl get events --field-selector involvedObject.kind=Pod | grep Warning
```

[image]

To see the same events in AKS, enable container logs in container insights.

[image]

Now navigate to logs in the AKS cluster and query kubeEvents. `KubeEvents | where ObjectKind contains "Pod"`

[image]

Comment: Wow thanks so much - I will try to test this today and report back

Comment: Well I tried to enable container insights but got an unrelated error.  That's something I can figure out separately.

Thanks again for the thorough answer